# Swift iOS Map an Array Of Doubles, Convert them to Date, then Sort

Tags: swift, sorting

I have a custom object that has a property of type `Double`. It gets initialized using `Date().timeIntervalSince9170`

```
Class MyObject {
    dateAdded: Double?
}

let myObject1 = MyObject()
myObject1.dateAdded = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

//myObjec2 and more myObjects get initialized and everything added to the array below

var arr = [MyObject]()
arr.append(myObject1)
arr.append(myObject2)
arr.append...
```

I later have a different array that gets initialized with all the objects from the array above and I want to sort by the dateAdded so I `map` each object

```
var diffArr = [MyObject]()
diffArr.map { Date(timeIntervalSince1970: $0.dateAdded!)}
```

**How can I then sort the diffArr after mapping it?**

I would normally do this but `compare` doesn't work on `Double`

```
diffArr.sort { (d1, d2) -> Bool in
    return d1.dateAdded?.compare(d2.dateAdded) == .orderedDescending
}
```

I looked at other q&a's but I couldn't find anything that does it all at once using Date

Comment: There's no need for the map in order to sort by `dateAdded`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dates` are `Comparable`, so you can just use

```
diffArr.sort { return $0.dateAdded ?? 0.0 < $1.dateAdded ?? 0.0 }
```

(The force-unwrap is bad mojo. Can you change your structs so the dateAdded property is not optional?)

In my code I wrote the comparison to map nil date values to 0, so MyObject instances with nil dates would have very early dates.

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice about the unwrapping. I’m going to upvote it for the tip. Since Khan answered first I’ll try his to see if it works for the problem then I’ll try yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

**op1:**

```
diffArr.sort(by:>)
```

and implement https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable protocol , if you want to use map for a result array not in-place

**op2:**

```
var dates = diffArr.map { Date(timeIntervalSince1970: $0.dateAdded!)} 
dates.sort { (d1, d2) -> Bool in
   return d1.compare(d2) == .orderedDescending
}
```

Comment: @SL_Khan hey thanks. What if I had other properties in the object, would that still work?

Comment: after you implement comparable make the compare only with **dateAdded** property

Comment: Isn’t that an entirely different array though? The reason I need it to be the same array is because a collectionview is using it and I’m constantly adding and removing things from the array. Every time that happens I need to sort the array again.

Comment: I tried option 1, it doesn’t work. I get an error that says: Ambiguous reference to member ‘>’.

Comment: In Sh_Khan's approach, you would need to make your `MyObject` class conform to the `Comparable` protocol, and in the implementation of the "<" operator you'd compare the `Date` values. Then when you compare `MyObject`s you would always compare them by `Date`. It would make sorting an array of  `MyObject`s by date simpler, but also make it less clear what criteria you were sorting them by.

Comment: @DuncanC how would I make MyObject conform to the Comparable protocol? Would I have to make dataAdded a Date type instead of a Double type?

Comment: Did you look up the comparable protocol? Try a Google search on "Conforming to the Comparable Protocol". You just need to implement the `<` and `==` operators, and declare that your class conforms. You can compare your dates as Doubles, or as Dates. Whichever is easier.